# UIOP does not recognize local-nicknames keyword

Tags: package, common-lisp, sbcl, asdf, uiop

I'm attempting to make a Lisp package with `uiop/package:define-package`. I'm using SBCL, and have confirmed that package-local nicknaming ought to be supported:

```lisp
* *features*
(:QUICKLISP :ASDF3.3 :ASDF3.2 :ASDF3.1 :ASDF3 :ASDF2 :ASDF :OS-UNIX
 :NON-BASE-CHARS-EXIST-P :ASDF-UNICODE :X86-64 :GENCGC :64-BIT :ANSI-CL
 :COMMON-LISP :ELF :IEEE-FLOATING-POINT :LINUX :LITTLE-ENDIAN
 :PACKAGE-LOCAL-NICKNAMES :SB-CORE-COMPRESSION :SB-LDB :SB-PACKAGE-LOCKS
 :SB-THREAD :SB-UNICODE :SBCL :UNIX)
* (uiop:featurep :package-local-nicknames)
T
```

Nevertheless, when I try to define a package that has local nicknames, it doesn't work:

```lisp
(uiop/package:define-package #:foo
  (:use #:cl)
  (:local-nicknames (#:b #:binparse)))

debugger invoked on a SIMPLE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1001878103}>:
  unrecognized define-package keyword :LOCAL-NICKNAMES

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(UIOP/PACKAGE:PARSE-DEFINE-PACKAGE-FORM #:FOO ((:USE #:CL) (:LOCAL-NICKNAMES (#:B #:BINPARSE))))
   source: (ERROR "unrecognized define-package keyword ~S" KW)
0] 0
```

(`binparse` being another package I've made, which worked fine, but which did not happen to use local nicknaming).

What I've found of [the `uiop/package` source](https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/asdf/asdf/-/blob/master/uiop/package.lisp#L744) seems to indicate that this shouldn't happen? Going by that, it should either work, or have a specific error message indicating the non-supported-ness of local nicknames (if somehow `uiop:featurep` is inaccurate or changing), but it shouldn't give a generic unknown-keyword error. At this point I'm not sure what I could be getting wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of `asdf` that's included in releases of `sbcl` is based on `asdf` version 3.3.1 (November 2017), except bundled into only two (larger) lisp files (one for `asdf` and one for `uiop`) rather than breaking them up by purpose as is done in official releases of `asdf`. `asdf` added `#+sbcl` support for package-local nicknames in 3.3.3.2 (August 2019), and switched to the more general `#+package-local-nicknames` in 3.3.4.1 (April 2020) (the latest *release* version is 3.3.4, though, so that wouldn't be in yet anyway). So it's "just" a delay in pulling from upstream. Following the instructions on [upgrading ASDF](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#Upgrading-ASDF) did the trick – extract [the latest release tarball](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/archives/asdf.tar.gz) into `~/common-lisp/asdf` and run `(load (compile-file #P"~/common-lisp/asdf/build/asdf.lisp"))` once, and future shells will use the updated version.